# Exchange seems to have two different Global Address Books. How do I get them back in Sync?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I've got a Hybrid Exchange setup with Office 365, and when I create a brand-new Outlook profile using the Outlook Desktop client, I get a bogus global address book with a bunch of users who left a long time ago, and are set to be hidden from the address book.

There seems to be more than one global address book, however, because if I check the global address book through webmail, it shows the correct address book.  If I check the global address book through Exchange Admin Console, it also shows the correct address book, both on-prem and in cloud.

Outlook desktop is somehow finding a faulty copy of the global address book, that exists separate from the actual global address book. How do I get this faulty copy of the Global Address book to synchronize?

Comment: By default, Outlook shows the Offline Global Address List. Is it up to date?

Comment: I'm creating an entirely new outlook profile from scratch.

Comment: My point is that Outlook uses the Offline Global Address List by default. A new Outlook profile isn't going to change that. If the Offline Global Address List isn't up to date than that's your problem.

Comment: It was my impression that the Offline Global Address list was something copied over from the exchange server to the Outlook client periodically. If you're saying that this "Offline global address list" is something hosted on the Exchange server separate from the "Global Address List", then the Offline Global Address List is the subject of my question.

Comment: The Offline Global Address is generated by the Exchange Server and is downloaded periodically by Outlook clients. If you select the Global Address List in Outlook and it's correct, then your problem is the Offline Address List, either on the Exchange server or in your Outlook client. Try running this on the Exchange Server from the EMS: **Update-OfflineAddressBook -Identity "Default Offline Address Book"**

Comment: Tried it. no change.

Comment: OK, let's take a step back. `1.` Is Outlook in cached mode? `2.` When you start a new message in Outlook, which Address List is being used? `3.` Does the Global Address List look correct in OWA?

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. The incorrect address book.  3. Yes

Comment: OK, clarify item number 2. Telling me the incorrect address book is displayed doesn't tell me **which** address book is incorrect. Start a new message, click the To button. note which address list is displayed in the dropdown, confirm that the address list member or members are missing. Then tell me which Address List it is.

Comment: "Global Address List" is displayed.  This address list has nothing missing. All the most recent users are present. It does, however, have a bunch of old users who have been marked as hidden from the address book.  These users don't show up when I check the Global Address List in OWA or in EAC.

Comment: Try running this from the AMS: **Update-GlobalAddressList -Identity "Default Global Address List"**

Comment: Tried that, but still not seeing any difference.

Comment: Hi, it sounds like due to remained Outlook ost file, please check if any remained file in \Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook. If it only occurs on one specific user, try downloading the address list manually, find "Send/Receive" - Send/Receive Groups- Download address book.

Comment: I deleted all .ost files, deleted all Outlook profiles, created a new Outlook profile, and downloaded the address list manually. Same problem.